# Can not change directory. Completely new at Ubuntu

Tags: cd-command

I am really new at ubuntu and I'm trying to set my directory to a certain file.
Whenever I set it to the folder with all my C++ files it says `No such file or directory`

I type in `cd /home/` and that works and `cd /home/aiteta` and that also works. But when I do `cd/home/aiteta/Desktop` it stops working. I've tried dragging my file to the terminal and it still doesn't work. I've used the ls command on `cd /home/aiteta/` and all it says is DrMemory-Linux-1.11.17799-1 and no other files are shown.

I would really love some help. Thank you! I am on Windows as well.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it stops working"_? Did you really issue `cd/home/aiteta/Desktop`? What was the outcome? This is missing a blank (space) between `cd` and the actual directory, i.e. it should be `cd /home/aiteta/Desktop`.

Comment: Yes I did add a space, I wrote exactly cd /home/aiteta/Desktop "-bash: cd: /home/aiteta/Desktop: No such file or directory". This is the output

Comment: What does `ls -la $HOME | grep '^d'` show? It should list all the directories in your $HOME directory and `Desktop` should be part of it.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 1 aiteta aiteta       512 Oct 18 14:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         512 Oct  3 10:24 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 aiteta aiteta       512 Oct  3 11:18 DrMemory-Linux-1.11.17799-1

Comment: The output shows you don't have a `Desktop` directory in your `$HOME` directory. What version of Ubuntu did you install? The server? Server version (as opposed to Desktop) doesn't create `Desktop` directories because the server usually doesn't include a graphical environment.

Comment: check the output of `ls ~.config/users-dirs.dirs` That would be the file to change if you want the desktop outside of your /home/ Another one: are you maybe using Windows version WSL? And not a separate installation?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have installed a localized version of ubuntu. That means that 'Desktop' is translatd to the language you chose on install. For german installations this means that the path to Desktop is `/home/user/Schreibtisch`. For me this is annoying and makes no semse.

You could try to find out like this:

Open a terminal by pressing ALT+SRG+T

In the terminal enter:

```
find $HOME -type d -maxdepth 1
```

In the output try to find the folder name that resembles "Desktop" in your local language. Hope it helps!

Comment: In a comment the OP showed there is only one directory below $HOME: `DrMemory-Linux-1.11.17799-1`.